# golang strange allocations in slice of pointers

Tags: go, pointers, slice, allocation

I have simple benchmark to compare performance for creating slice of structs and slice of pointers to that structs

```golang
package pointer

import (
    "testing"
)

type smallStruct struct {
    ID int
}

func newSmallStruct(id int) *smallStruct {
    return &smallStruct{ID: id}
}

func BenchmarkSmallStructPointer(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var slice = make([]*smallStruct, 0, 10000)
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
            t := newSmallStruct(n + i)
            slice = append(slice, t)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkSmallStruct(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        var slice = make([]smallStruct, 0, 10000)
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
            t := newSmallStruct(n + i)
            slice = append(slice, *t)
        }
    }
}
```

Result of benchmark

```
go test -bench . -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test-project/pointer
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
BenchmarkSmallStructPointer-4               3121            328864 ns/op          161921 B/op      10001 allocs/op
BenchmarkSmallStruct-4                     29218             48021 ns/op           81920 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Please, explain me, what operation produced so many allocations for slice of pointers? It seems to be append to slice, but I don't understand why?

Comment: The allocations are not from the slice, they are from each value you allocate; every `&smallStruct` needs to be allocated _somewhere_

Comment: @JimB but why no allocations in benchmark without pointer? There is the same variable t

Comment: You are not storing the value allocated by `newSmallStruct` within `BenchmarkSmallStruct`, you are copying the value into the already pre-allocated slice. The compiler sees this and knows the pointer doesn't escape so there's no need to allocate it on the heap.

Comment: It's really compiler magic, if replace iteration limit in inner loop from 10000 to len(slice), the benchmark result becomes

```BenchmarkSmallStructPointerNew-4           30586             32790 ns/op           81920 B/op          1 allocs/op```

No unnecessary allocations!

Comment: using `len(slice)` has no allocations because `len(slice)` is `0`, you didn't add anything to the slice at all

Answer (score 0):

Go has a feature called "escape analysis" that logs what values escape to the heap — and why.

It's enabled with a compiler flag with optional verbosity: `-gcflags='-m=2'`. You can set it on `go test`, `go build`, `go run`. (Anything that passes that flag along to `go tool compile`)

Using this we can see that `&smallStruct` escapes to the heap, forcing an allocation. If I'm interpreting the results correctly, it's because even though `newSmallStruct` is inlined in both testcases, the compiler is able to see that the pointer is immediately dereferenced in the second case. Whereas the first case continues to pass the pointer to other functions (`append`):

```
> go test -bench=. -benchmem -gcflags='-m=2' .
# ...

./main_test.go:12:9: &smallStruct{...} escapes to heap:
./main_test.go:12:9:   flow: ~r0 = &{storage for &smallStruct{...}}:
./main_test.go:12:9:     from &smallStruct{...} (spill) at ./main_test.go:12:9
./main_test.go:12:9:     from return &smallStruct{...} (return) at ./main_test.go:12:2

# ...
./main_test.go:29:23: &smallStruct{...} does not escape
```

With higher verbosity (3):

```
./main_test.go:19:23: &smallStruct{...} escapes to heap:
./main_test.go:19:23:   flow: ~R0 = &{storage for &smallStruct{...}}:
./main_test.go:19:23:     from &smallStruct{...} (spill) at ./main_test.go:19:23
./main_test.go:19:23:     from ~R0 = &smallStruct{...} (assign-pair) at ./main_test.go:19:23
./main_test.go:19:23:   flow: t = ~R0:
./main_test.go:19:23:     from t := ~R0 (assign) at ./main_test.go:19:6
./main_test.go:19:23:   flow: {heap} = t:
./main_test.go:19:23:     from append(slice, t) (call parameter) at    <--
./main_test.go:20:18
```

This talk goes over various situations in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMZpH4yT7M0

### Optimizing around this

Even without `append` — using plain index-assignment - this will cause a heap allocation.

This is because if `&smallStruct{...}` was allocated in the stack frame of `newSmallStruct()`, that address could be overwritten later. Go re-uses old function stack space for new ones. Allocating in the heap here is the "verifiably correct" thing to do.

If you have a case where you *need* to optimize this away for performance, create the value-only slice first — ideally return a value from `newSmallStruct()` so it works when not inlined. Then make the pointer-slice reference those local values.

```golang
func BenchmarkSmallStructPointer(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        vslice := make([]smallStruct, 0, 10000)
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
            t := newSmallStruct(n + i)
            vslice = append(vslice, *t)
        }

        slice := make([]*smallStruct, len(vslice))
        for i := 0; i < len(vslice); i++ {
            slice[i] = &vslice[i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
BenchmarkSmallStructPointer-8              45446             25011 ns/op          163840 B/op          2 allocs/op
```